# Trying to debug apps from eclipse on android

Tags: android

I am developing apps for android and I bought an bq Maxwell 2 Lite, and I wanted to test them in the device, but i can't seem to do it... can somebody help me with that?

The android version on the device is 4.1.1 and I have enabled debugging throw USB.

Thank you all for your time and thanks for all the help

Carlos Morgado

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain a little bit more, what you want to do and what you've tried.

Comment: Please do accept the answer that helped you solve the problem , or post the solution that you found. So that it could help others.

Answer (score 1):

For using USB debugging in eclipse, make sure that you have all the drivers installed. Open sdk manager, under extras you can see Google USB drivers, make sure that this is downloaded.

If after this also it didn't work, go to device management if you are using windows and find your device. Right click on your device and update device drivers, update from my computer and give this folder `sdk folder\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. Set platform-tools folder in your path variables and run these commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

You can see list of attached devices using this command:

```
adb devices
```

Comment: I finally got the drivers, but when i do adb devices the list is clear, and none of the other commands you gave seem to work

Answer (score 1):

So to test with any device you need

1. Install the driver for the device on your OS.
2. Enable USB debugging on your device.
3. Plug-in the device through an USB.
4. Run the app through the [IDE](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) and select the configured device to run the application

[This](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) should help you get started.